# Is it OK to have too long RESTful endpoint?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, design-patterns, controller, restful-url

My service has 3 kinds of model classes which are `User`, `Project`, `Simulation`.

The problem is `Project`s are consist of 6 levels.

`User` > `Proejct(lv1)` > `Project(lv2)` > `Project(lv3)` > `Project(lv4)` > `Project(lv5)` > `Project(lv6)` > `Simulation`

I made a `RESTful` endpoint URL based on the hierarchy,
and the final result looks like this.

```
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/team-members/{userId}/divisions/{divisionId}/products/{productId}/bgatypes/{bgaTypeId}/devices/{deviceId}/ballcounts/{ballCountId}/pkgsizes/{pkgSizeId}/simulations
```

I wonder if I'm doing the wrong design of RESTful protocol since the URL is becoming too long.

Is it better to use query parameters instead of path variables?
Any advice will be thankful.

**+Another idea**

I'm thinking to change to make it shorter and this is my idea.
Since each result has only one parent, I want to query them with only giving one parameter which is `parentId`, so It will look like this.

```
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/team-members
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/divisions?userId=user1
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/products?divisionId=division32
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/bgatypes?productId=product402
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/devices?bgaTypeId=bgatype777
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/ballcounts?deviceId=device139
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/pkgsizes?ballCountId=ballcount587
http://MY_SERVER.com/rest/project/simulations?pkgSizeId=pkgsize591
```

Does this against RESTful protocol? Which is better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on what you mean by `levels` within your project. In REST, each resource (such as an Model of a database table, an `entity`) should be a path variable. This would be defined as `/resource/{resourceId}`. If you have a sub-resource, say a `User` has a `Project`, then you would have `/user/{userId}/project/{projectId}`.

If levels are attributes of a `Project`, then you may want to use query parameters. You'd have to clarify more on what levels are and what you're exactly trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The level means parent and children. It's similar to a folder. Each `Project`s have sub `Project`s which cannot be shared and each sub `Project`s have only one parent `Project`.

Comment: @wonsuc In that case, I think your first approach is correct. Since a child `subproject` is a sub-resource of the parent `project`, that should be reflected in the URL via path parameters. `/project/{projectId}/subproject/{subprojectId}/subsubproject/{subsubprojectId}`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you also check my updated question?

Comment: No problem! There is nothing _bad_ about your second approach, but it doesn't particularly follow REST best practices, but a valid approach to an API. I'd probably do something like `/project/{projectId}/parent/{parentId}`... and so on, e.g. `/project/devices/parent/bgatype777`, since `bgatype777` is the parent ID for a specific `device` resource.